# Getting of list of implicit properties declared in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am in the process of taking over a pretty large angular project from another developer. One thing I noticed was there are a lot of undeclared properties being assigned in the html markup and not declared in the controller.

I am fully aware Angular takes care of creating these properties anyway. But its best practices to declare everything in the controller so other developers won't have to hunt them down.

Is there anyway to get a list of non-explicitly declared properties on a controller? So I can clean it up a bit?

Thank you!

Comment: Search for every instance of ng-model in your markup? Dreadful, I know.

Comment: Besides ng-model, you  have to look in any `ng-` directive because you can declare them in `ng-init`, `ng-click`, etc.  I'm with @m.casey it can be dreadful.

Comment: yea...I was hoping to use reflection and hoping those properties that were created implicitly would have some way to identify they were created that way. :). Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable method is probably output $scope to the console:

```
console.log($scope);
```

You'll see the AngularJS bits ($$somethingSomething), but you're sure to see all the undeclared bits as well. The alternative is to take a text based approach by searching for ng-* tags, but would probably be worse.